# How to make scrollable table 100% of the remaining width of the container, but not the screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In my application I have sidebar (collapced bar) on the left "sidebar-left" and container with different type of content on the right "content". And I can't deal with width of this container, it must take 100% of remaining width, and different types of content it work's good, but if I place the scrollable table in this "content" container it allways try to stretch this table in 100% of the screen size, but not container size, and width of the screen enlarges in the width of sidebar size. Here is my page:

```css
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-left {
      width: 300px;
      background: red;
    }

    .content {
      /*width: calc(100% - 300px);  it works, but .sidebar-left should have flexible size*/
      width: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-right {
      width: 20px;
      background: blue;
    }

    .scrollable-table {
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 100%;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 4</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-left">
            Sidebar left
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div data-v-e474bf0e="" class="scrollable-table">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
                    <thead><tr><th class="sticky-first-column text-center">№ документа</th> <th class="sticky-second-column text-center">Дата</th> <th class="text-center">ст. Відправлення</th> <th class="text-center">ст. Призначення</th> <th class="text-center">Відправник</th> <th class="text-center">Отримувач</th> <th class="text-center">Вантаж</th> <th class="text-center">К-ть вагонів</th> <th class="text-center">Маса вантажу</th></tr></thead> 
                    <tbody><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33168097</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(341408) славута i</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(400409) одесса-порт (эксп.)</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(5711) Админитрация Одесского Морского Порта комплекс ЗПК ООО «Бруклин-Киев»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">5</td> <td class="text-right">3 477,60</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33169244</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(334008) красилов</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">1</td> <td class="text-right">694,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33169301</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(334008) красилов</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">3</td> <td class="text-right">2 087,00</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33169343</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(334008) красилов</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">4</td> <td class="text-right">2 792,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">35991256</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(350303) дубно</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">8</td> <td class="text-right">5 388,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">35997469</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(350303) дубно</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">8</td> <td class="text-right">5 438,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">40831539</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(416604) блакитное</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(424507) ксениево (эксп.)</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3804) ООО «ИЗТ» для ПИИ «ГЛЕНКОР АГРІКАЛЧЕР УКРАЇНА»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(014003) Ячмень</td> <td class="text-right">4</td> <td class="text-right">2 358,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">43300730</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(443300) лихачево</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(2481) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3566) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">10</td> <td class="text-right">6 932,00</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to make `width: calc(100% - 300px);` but sidebar must be collapced, and it  size varies from 80 to 300 px.
I have found common questions but solutions doesn't works in my case. It allways try to stretch .content div in 100% width of the screen, but not remaining width.

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative units for the widths. For example `vw` which is the width of the viewport ('screen width' if you want).

vh = height of view port

Here I used 10vw and 90vw but you can adjust.

```css
.wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-left {
      width: 10vw;
      background: red;
    }

    .content {
      width: 90vw;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-right {
      width: 20px;
      background: blue;
    }

    .scrollable-table {
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 100%;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 4</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-left">
            Sidebar left
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div data-v-e474bf0e="" class="scrollable-table">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
                    <thead><tr><th class="sticky-first-column text-center">№ документа</th> <th class="sticky-second-column text-center">Дата</th> <th class="text-center">ст. Відправлення</th> <th class="text-center">ст. Призначення</th> <th class="text-center">Відправник</th> <th class="text-center">Отримувач</th> <th class="text-center">Вантаж</th> <th class="text-center">К-ть вагонів</th> <th class="text-center">Маса вантажу</th></tr></thead> 
                    <tbody><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33168097</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(341408) славута i</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(400409) одесса-порт (эксп.)</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(5711) Админитрация Одесского Морского Порта комплекс ЗПК ООО «Бруклин-Киев»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">5</td> <td class="text-right">3 477,60</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33169244</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(334008) красилов</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">1</td> <td class="text-right">694,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33169301</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(334008) красилов</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">3</td> <td class="text-right">2 087,00</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33169343</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(334008) красилов</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">4</td> <td class="text-right">2 792,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">35991256</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(350303) дубно</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">8</td> <td class="text-right">5 388,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">35997469</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(350303) дубно</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">8</td> <td class="text-right">5 438,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">40831539</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(416604) блакитное</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(424507) ксениево (эксп.)</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3804) ООО «ИЗТ» для ПИИ «ГЛЕНКОР АГРІКАЛЧЕР УКРАЇНА»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(014003) Ячмень</td> <td class="text-right">4</td> <td class="text-right">2 358,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">43300730</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(443300) лихачево</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(2481) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3566) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">10</td> <td class="text-right">6 932,00</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, but I can do the same with %, the main problem that sidebar must be collapced, and in size of the screen 1500 pixels it size is 300 px and in screen less than 768 px it should be 80 px. This is very strange that there are no way to make div that will fill 100% of remaining width. When I specify the exact width of container all work's good, but why browser can't calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

By using CSS custom properties (variables), we can achieve this.

Try this.

```
:root {
--sidebar-left: 300px; /* sidebar width */

}
.wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-left {
      width: 300px;
      background: red;
    }

    .content {
      width: calc(100% - var(--sidebar-left));
    }

    .sidebar-right {
      width: 20px;
      background: blue;
    }

    .scrollable-table {
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 100%;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
:root {
--sidebar-left: 80px; /* sidebar width for screen sizes less than 768px */
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank's god I found the solution, to avoid grown width of content container it must has style `overfrow: hidden`, and now when I place my scrollable table in this container it  fills all remaining width, and don't enlarge main container.

Here is the result code:

```css
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
    }

    .sidebar-left {
      width: 300px;
      background: red;
    }

    .content {
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .scrollable-table {
        overflow: scroll;
        white-space:nowrap;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 4</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-left">
            Sidebar left
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div data-v-e474bf0e="" class="scrollable-table">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
                    <thead><tr><th class="sticky-first-column text-center">№ документа</th> <th class="sticky-second-column text-center">Дата</th> <th class="text-center">ст. Відправлення</th> <th class="text-center">ст. Призначення</th> <th class="text-center">Відправник</th> <th class="text-center">Отримувач</th> <th class="text-center">Вантаж</th> <th class="text-center">К-ть вагонів</th> <th class="text-center">Маса вантажу</th></tr></thead> 
                    <tbody><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33168097</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(341408) славута i</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(400409) одесса-порт (эксп.)</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(5711) Админитрация Одесского Морского Порта комплекс ЗПК ООО «Бруклин-Киев»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">5</td> <td class="text-right">3 477,60</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33169244</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(334008) красилов</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">1</td> <td class="text-right">694,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33169301</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(334008) красилов</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">3</td> <td class="text-right">2 087,00</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">33169343</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(334008) красилов</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">4</td> <td class="text-right">2 792,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">35991256</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(350303) дубно</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">8</td> <td class="text-right">5 388,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">35997469</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(350303) дубно</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3511) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">8</td> <td class="text-right">5 438,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">40831539</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(416604) блакитное</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(424507) ксениево (эксп.)</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(8346) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3804) ООО «ИЗТ» для ПИИ «ГЛЕНКОР АГРІКАЛЧЕР УКРАЇНА»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(014003) Ячмень</td> <td class="text-right">4</td> <td class="text-right">2 358,50</td></tr><tr><td class="sticky-first-column text-center">43300730</td> <td class="sticky-second-column text-center">10.09.2020</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(443300) лихачево</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(403002) черноморская (эксп. для тис )</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(2481) ТОВ "УТЛ-2"</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(3566) ООО «ТИС» для ООО «М.В.КАРГО»</td> <td class="text-capitalize">(011005) Пшеница</td> <td class="text-right">10</td> <td class="text-right">6 932,00</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```